# Set a secret key with command line in Django for saleor installation on windows

Tags: python, django, saleor

I'm trying to install saleor on Windows, in the SECRET_KEY part throws an error saying that my SECRET_KEY cannot be empty, I suppose it must be entered by commands. What command is used in Windows to set a SECRET_KEY in Django and then continue to the next step of installing saleor?

Comment: The SECRET_KEY is just a long random string in your settings.py file. Check your settings.py file.

Comment: That's the funny thing because the settings.py doesn't exist in the entire project, I've searching for this file a lot of hours an it doesn't exist, the repo with the files is https://github.com/mirumee/saleor

Comment: Have you actually followed the [installation instructions](https://docs.getsaleor.com/docs/getting-started/installation-windows/) step by step? How about step 4???

Comment: The settings.py file is in **saleor/saleor/settings.py** but as the instructions suggest, don’t add the SECRET_KEY there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, settings.py exist indeed, you will found it inside "saleor" folder where you have cloned the project. 
In settings.py you'll found:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
```

Which means that you really haven't a secret key setted up. Instead of this it will be capturing it from your environment variables, so here you must setup it:

Open a command prompt and type: `setx SECRET_KEY "<your secret key>"`
(another method here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEroNNzqlF4)

Your secret key can be "hello" if you're just testing, or can generate a "real" key here: https://www.miniwebtool.com/django-secret-key-generator/

Regards!